# Trying to list out FB friends pictures using Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to set up a call that will list out a certain number of a friends pictures for a logged in facebook user.  It works to spit out the users' picture, but I cannot get the call for fb friends pictures.  I'm sure you guys can solve this easily.  Here is the code:

```
<?php

    if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']))
    {
        ?>


<?php
    }
    else{


        if (!class_exists('FacebookApiException')) {
            require_once('./src/facebook.php' );
        }
        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                                       'appId' => $appId,
                                       'secret' => $appSecret,
                                       ));


        $fbuser = $facebook->getUser();

        echo $fbuser;

        echo $_SESSION['user_name'];
        echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'.$fbuser.'/picture">';

        echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'.$fbuser.'/friends/picture">';



        echo '<a href="?logout=1">Log Out</a>';
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to get a list of the user friends calling `/me?fields=friends`. Then, you can only add their id to the picture urls just like you did with the user:

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/{{friend_id}}/picture">
```